# verificar se valor GET existe ou não

Tags: php, array

Criei um array chamando nomes, dentro dessa array possuo 3 nomes

```
$nomes = array ('carlos', 'maria', 'jose')
```

Mais a frente no codigo eu to tentando criar um if onde verifica se o valor de GET existe dentro dessa array, porém não estou conseguindo. Tentei fazer isso só que não deu certo.

```
if($_GET['pg'] == $nomes){ echo "existe";}else{echo "nao existe";}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar o [**in_array()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) do PHP, que verifica se essa string existe numa dada array.

Pode colocar `in_array($_GET['pg'], $nomes)` dentro do `if()` para verificar se existe um membro da array igual ao valor de `$_GET['pg']`.

```
$nomes = array('carlos', 'maria', 'jose');
if(in_array($_GET['pg'], $nomes))  echo "existe";
else echo "nao existe";
```

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a função [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) para fazer essa comparação, o primeiro argumento é o valor a ser encontrado e o segundo é em qual variavel deve ser feita a pesquisa no caso `$nomes`.

```
$nomes = array ('carlos', 'maria', 'jose');

$_GET['pg'] = 'carlos';
if(in_array($_GET['pg'], $nomes)){
    echo 'nome '. $_GET['pg']  .' encontrado';
}
```